# Searching a firewall for web with html keyword replacing capabilities

Tags: firefox, browser, firewall, html, keyword

I'm searching for an utility (better free) or an add-on for Firefox that intercepts the http traffic and replaces or deletes some keywords in the html source, basing on a pre-defined  user edited list. So that I could have a 'cleaner' web experience.

Example 1: I would like to replace every occurrence of "http://www.mybestwebsite.com/ugly-ads" with an empty string, so that I can still see the website "http://www.mybestwebsite.com", but I don't see anymore the ugly ads from that same website.

Example 2: I would like to replace every occurence of " nastyword " with "-censored-".

Does a utility like the one described, or a firewall with this kind of content filter ability, or an Add-on for Firefox with the same features exist?

EDIT: sorry, I forgot to mention: It should work under windowsXP and/or w7

Comment: Squid with dansguardian will allow you to do some of that.. if not all of it, it's not simple though: http://dansguardian.org/

Comment: BTW, dansguardian can be integrated with firewall software, like smoothwall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an "utility" [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) can do that very nice and it's very lightweight. And it runs on [Win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ijbswa/files/Win32/) platforms.

Configuration in detail:

for Example 1 use Path patterns to modify paths as desired.

for Example 2 use "filter" directives to change page contents you want on the fly

You can find some basic rulesets around for it aswell.

Of course it's not browser dependent so it applies to any browser you may like.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it: it works well with the path patterns; while with the filters I still have some problems; i.e.  if I define a new filter in the file "user.filter" (or even in "default.filter") like "s/badword/bepolite/g" it does not work. Well I'll have to read a bit more the documentation. Anyway, thanks!